# Проблема при компиляции приложения

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Красным выделено **nav_host_fragment** и в консоли **Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.**
Приложение не запускается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
    package com.example.class333333333;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Полный код класса текстом и файл разметки для `MainActivity` в вопрос добавьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Готово.⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: Разметки-то все еще нету)

Comment: Объясните⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: файл `activity_main.xml`

Comment: @OleggOmelnitskiy
Требуется код файла activity_main.xml. А так же советую добавить флаг -Xlint:deprecation в конфигуации Вашей сборки.

Comment: Всё.............

Comment: В правом верхнем углу `activity_main.xml` три иконки, сейчас подсвечена самая правая (с картинкой). Выберете самую левую из трех - появится текстовое представление файла, которое можно будет скопировать в вопрос. Средняя иконка позволяет одновременно просматривать и текстовое представление и окно дизайна*

Comment: Добавил код activity_main

Comment: nav_host_fragment эта ошибка ищите там